# Convert JSONObject to Map in a functional way

Tags: java, stream, spliterator

I have a simple JSONObject like

```
{"name": "dido"}
```

Now I want that to convert to a Map, so I wrote:

```
Map<String, String> newMap = StreamSupport
                .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(obj.keys(), Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> obj.get(v)));
```

obj is an instance of **JSONObject**. *obj.keys()* returns an *Iterator* and *obj.get()* returns the value at this key.

Why do I get an error? How can I fix it in a functional way?

Comment: "Why do I get an error?" Did I miss something? What error did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I fixed it. Java couldn't infer the String.

```
Map<String, String> newMap = StreamSupport
                .stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(obj.keys(), Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), obj::getString));
```